# Game center not enabled for new app id iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, provisioning, game-center

I have already submitted one game to App Store, it's now live. Now my client wants to integrate Game Center into the app and submit an update.

In the first version we have created a distribution profile for `.*` bundle id. From my research I found that game center is enabled only for the `com.companyname.app`-like bundle id.

When I'm creating a new app id with `.*`, Game Center is not enabled. How do I submit update of my game?

Answer (score 0):

I may be totally wrong, but I'd create a new Application Id with bundle id matching your app's one and using the same bundle seed you used for a wildcard application. (All these steps are done in Provisioning Portal).

AFAIK after this steps you'll be able to enable Game Center for your app and use the same Provisioning Profile for distribution. E.g. you won't have to change your app's `Info.plist` at all.

Answer (score 0):

from the ios dev center:

Wildcard App IDs and duplicates of existing explicit App IDs are ineligible for In App Purchase and Game Center.

So if you have a wildcard in your app id (i.e. a "*" in it), Game Center is ineligible.

By the way, I have the same problem, so if you found the solution, please do share it. Thanks